# How to get react-router and react-redux to play nicely?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

Preface I have no interest in react-router-redux I do not at all want location as part of my state tree.

Original set up was as follows:

```
let routes = (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <Route path='/' component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage} onEnter={_ensureLoggedIn}/>
        <Route path="login" component={ SessionForm }/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
)

let provider = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    {routes}
  </Provider>
);

function _ensureLoggedIn(nextState, replace, callback) {
  let hasBeenFetched = store.getState().currentUser.hasBeenFetched;
  let loggedIn = !!store.getState().currentUser.id;
  if (hasBeenFetched) {
    _redirectIfNotLoggedIn();
  } else {
    store.dispatch(Actions.fetchCurrentUser());
  }
  function _redirectIfNotLoggedIn() {
    if (!loggedIn) {
      replace({}, "/login");
    }
    callback();
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(provider, root);
```

with this attempt, no components have access to the store (the entire point of using provider..?)

Ok cool so some digging reveals that you routes have to be generated inside of provider or else it doesnt work.

I replace {routes} inside Provider with the actual list of routes.

Still doesn't work... the most important aspect here is disabling access to the majority of routes if the user is not logged in. Its very easy to ensure this when all the work is done in the index.js file, but it is going to get messy if I have to start passing the store around (the entire point of using provider........)

Comment: How were you accessing the store before? Were you not using `connect` function?

Comment: The code above seems okay. Can you share how you're trying to access the store from the DOM?